# Rhino Mocks - AssertWasCalled when one parameter is DateTime.Now

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm writing Unit Tests for a C# Log-class that calls a log method on an interface ILogHandler with a timestamp prepended like so:

```
log(string msg, LogLevel lvl)
{
   _handler.log(DateTime.Now, msg, lvl);
}
```

My initial handler-method added the timestamp within the handler-method, which made it easy to test if the handlers log was called, but now that I've added the timestamp I'm uncertain as to how I should perform the test.

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide arguments expectations:

```
handler.AssertWasCalled(h => h.Log(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Anything, 
                                   Arg<string>.Is.Equal(msg),
                                   Arg<LogLevel>.Is.Equal(lvl)));
```

This will check, that first parameter passed to dependency is any DateTime. If you want to set some restrictions, add Arg.Matches part to argument.